# Unable to access High-Power USB device connected via USB OTG

Tags: usb, usb-on-the-go

I have a Samsung A52 [SM-A525F/DS] phone, a USB A to type C OTG cable. I wanted to connect my Audio Interface to the phone via the OTG. Audio Interface has 2 USB port, 1 for power and the other for data transfer. The Audio Interface powered from separate power supply. The problem is whenever i tried to connect it to the phone using the OTG cable, my phone always show 2 messages:

The first messages are:

1. Android System

   **Charging connected device via USB**

   Tap for other options.

The second messages are:

2. Android System

   **High-power USB device connected**

   Unable to access this device. Connected device needs external power supply

What have I done wrong here? Is there anything I missed in this step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to believe what the Android is telling you.  The Audio device is trying to suck too much power.  I can see two options

1. Either you have connected the power cable from the Audio to the Phone
2. The Audio device is not separating the power received on one plug from the other.

   - If this is the case, it could damage your phone.
   - Try using a USB hub to isolate the Audio device

Comment: Thank you, sir. I will try get some powered USB Hub and see if this will solve my problems. I will share the results here.